# Question regarding constrained optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

I have an exercise that says: Given $Q(x) = 3x_1^2+8x_1x_2+9x_2^2$ find a unit vector $x$ that minimizes $Q(x)$ subject to constraint $x^Tx=1$.

I set up $A=$$\begin{bmatrix}3&4\\4&9\end{bmatrix}$ and found the eigenvalues of this matrix to be $λ_1=11$ and $λ_2=1$ and the corresponding unit eigenvectors $u_1=$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}$ and $u_2=$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{-2}{\sqrt 5}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\end{bmatrix}$. I then applied a transformation $x=Py$ and get the new equation $Q(y)=11y_1^2+y_2^2$ which my professor just rewrites as $Q(x)=11x_1^2+x_2^2$ (to match the x variable notation used by the constraints I guess?). Anyways, to get the minimum, I need to add the constraint $x^Tu_1=0$, which according to my textbook results in $Q(x)=x_2^2$.

**My Question:** How does $x^Tu_1=0$ for the constraint? If I plug in $u_1$ to that equation there is no way I can get $x^T$ which results in $x^Tu_1=0$ to get the equation $Q(x)=x_2^2$. (I know the minimize procedure can be done without using $x^Tu_1=0$, but I wanted to do it this way to show the question I have).

**Note:** I apologize if the wording of this question is a little messy/scattered. I didn't really know how to explain it better than this. I think the issue might be how the notation is presented in the textbook I'm using but I'm not sure. Many thanks to anyone who can help clear things up for me here.

Comment: Before anyone asks: yes, I have done my research before asking this question. I have spent over 3 committed hours in trying to figure this out using my notes, textbook, and internet. Thanks again to anyone who can help me out on this.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the requirement of a constraint.  As you related the problem in the opening sentence, $x$ is to be "a unit vector" and $x^T x = 1$ .  These are redundant;  unit vectors are those with unit length.  By the end of the next paragraph you have introduced $x^T u_1 = 0$, which seems extraneous.  Did I misunderstand what you meant by "I need to add the constraint"?  Did you notice that $u_2$ is already orthogonal to $u_1$?

Comment: In a situation where A undergoes $x=Py$  transformation and a Q is obtained with 3 terms, if I wanted to get the second largest maximum, I would need to use the constraint $x^Tu_1=0$ to get $Q(x)=bx_2^2+cx_3^2$ and with this I would obtain the next largest maximum (second eigenvalue). I should have asked the question utilizing this example instead of the one in the question I asked, but I was already done typing my question when I realized this. In the example I posted in the question, yes it is redundant, but I just want to know how $x^Tu_1$=0 makes $Q(x)=bx_2^2+cx_3^2$ (how it removes $x_1$)

Comment: I'm having difficulty responding in a way that you'll find matches your studies.  Possibly you have been shown similar problems by a professor.  In any case you found the real eigenvalues and a pair of corresponding unit eigenvectors for them in connection with the real symmetric matrix that represents the quadratic form.  At that point you are essentially done... the minimum of $Q(x)$ is attained by a unit vector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue.  I'm just not sure where you need more help. [more]

Comment: Based on the last comment, I'm guessing you want to understand how a change of variables succeeds in *diagonalizing* the quadratic form, i.e. getting rid of the mixed terms $x_1x_2$ that appeared in the original statement.  But in its present form the Question's body scarcely touches on this.